# A word that describes goofing off at work that can be used as an adjective in front of the word activity?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

For example:

> The unreliable employee often engaged in **__** activities like smoke breaks, smalltalk with his fellows, and playing Solitaire during work hours.
>
> On Friday afternoons, the employees would often goof off and perform **__** activities.
>
> Fred's mind often wandered while performing menial tasks and he thought about **__** activities he would rather be doing.

Best candidates so far:

> counter-productive/non-productive/unproductive
>
> unprofessional (?)

**Bonus**: Come up with a word that eliminates the need for the word activity altogether:

> The project will not get finished any sooner if you keep wasting time on **__**.

Comment: "He was engaged in a *StackExchange* activity."

Comment: @Robusto: ! One could press non-task-oriented into use.

Comment: What's wrong with "distractions" (or "_distracting_ activities")?

Comment: @J.R., can distracting be used as an adjective?

Comment: Sure, what else would it be? [**distracting**](http://onelook.com/?w=distracting&ls=a) (adj.) [1](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/distracting) serving to distract; taking away your attention [2](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/distracting) preventing you from concentrating on something. As for your bonus, just use *distractions* (defined as _something that gets your attention and prevents you from concentrating on something else; a diversion_)

Comment: i would argue that I'm just (if not more) productive than other workers, even though I do go out for a smoke and occasionally engage is smalltalk. Your language smells of stalinist management unless you start being a lot clearer. Most adjectives that come up in such situations only highlight a prejudice and dislike for the employee, rather than being accurate descriptors. Thus, avoid them mostly. You could say instead that the employee often instigates in non-work related conversations which is time wasteful for all concerned. A certain amount of sociability is required for humans to function.

Comment: No one seems to have commented about why this should be closed. Obviously it's a good question put the wrong way. Could have been one sentence, instead. Voting to close as a non-Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **counter-productive** with activity. It's professional and fits all of your examples.

For a noun: **Shenanigans.** "We might go home early if there aren't any more shenanigans around the water cooler this afternoon.

> Shenanigans: high-spirited or mischievous activity —usually used in plural

Comment: That certainly fits the bill.

Comment: or "non-productive"

Answer (score 3):

I would refer to activities at work that aren't work-related as [slacking](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slacking)

> **slack**:
>   To evade work; shirk.

Comment: The word needs to be usable as an adjective in front of the word activity.

Answer (score 1):

How about some of these options:

> Often engaged in *diddle-daddle* like smoke breaks...
>
> Often engaged in *procrastination* like smoke breaks...
>
> Often engaged in *fritter* like smoke breaks...
>
> Often engaged in *trifles* like smoke breaks...
>
> Often engaged in *vacuities* like smoke breaks...
>
> Often engaged in *trifles* like smoke breaks...
>
> Often engaged in *fluff* like smoke breaks...

Answer (score 0):

A related term (that doesn't cover all you've asked for) is *government work*.  From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close_enough_for_government_work) (emphasis added):

> When something was “good enough for Government work” it meant it could pass the most rigorous of standards. Over the years it took on an ironic meaning that is now the primary sense, referring to poorly executed work.
>
> “Government work” is also a term for the **manufacture of something on company time for personal use**. For example, a custom trailer hitch made at a welding shop for the welder himself on the afternoon shift with no supervisors around is government work.

Comment: Similarly, **G-job** can be used to refer to a personal project pursued with company resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "unproductive activities" or even "unauthorized activities".

Comment: So close and yet so far...

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn, care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *personal* or *time-wasting* as your adjective.