# One word for "to take advantage of company resources (that one works for) for one's personal intents"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

This happens a lot at work, and I don't think there's a single word for it - or is there?

Examples:

1. Browsing the web for content unrelated to work
2. Taking company time for personal grooming (like painting nails, shaving, etc.)
3. Using the company refrigerator to temporarily store one's groceries purchased at lunch.
4. Printing stuff not related to work (worse yet, if it's material for employment somewhere else.)

Stealing is not specific enough.

Comment: In the "old" days, it used to mean copping a roll of scotch tape to use when wrapping Christmas presents.  I can see how that concept has so many more applications in this technically advanced world!

Comment: Also see  [A word that describes goofing off at work that can be used as an adjective in front of the word activity?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/92659),

Comment: "Perks of the job."

Comment: See also: workplaceSE beta

Comment: There might be single words for _some_ of these actions, but I doubt there is one that covers all of them. For example, although I have come across companies that considered browsing the Internet for non-work-related content to be a type of theft, I have never come across any that were not okay with employees temporarily storing their lunch or groceries in the fridge if there is one.

Comment: **theft** is a word used in corporations to refer to any and all of the above

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is called property conversion.

Comment: @PhilSweet Is time property?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was referring to filling the fridge, which denies the fridge owner their right to make it available to all employees.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Actually, I may have misunderstood what you wrote. I though you meant you had never come across any *terms* referring to this, but it looks like you meant people.

Comment: @Phil Oh, I see. I think we’re interpreting the question differently—I think I may have missed the “groceries” bit when I first read the question. I was talking about just keeping your lunch and a carton of milk in the fridge (as one of “all employees”), not about taking up all the space for yourself. I read the question as implying that the company fridge is completely off-limits to employees, which I’ve never see. (Yes, I did mean I’d never seen any companies that actually restrict things like that, not that I’d never come across terms for it.)

Answer (score 5):

There are many terms with different shades of meaning depending on the level of taking and the policies of the workplace. Some are

> - *misappropriation* (of company resources)
> - *diversion* (of company resources)
> - *skimming*
> - *embezzlement*
> - *goofing off* (misuse of time)
> - *cooping* (slang term for sleeping while on duty)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a question for "morality.stackexchange.com".

There is indeed one word:

> `stealing,`

unless of course the employer has explicitly allowed it.

Comment: “Stealing is not specific enough.”

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung My point was that in whatever way we describe this activity, it still comes into the general category of theft.

Comment: Technically, much of what the OP described is property conversion.

Answer (score 0):

An informal word to describe this act is **sponge**.

> The person is sponging the company's resources.

Answer (score 0):

'cynical exploitation' is closer to what you want I think. If this is done while pretending to be loyal, I would add the word 'subversive'

Comment: Please enhance your answer with some references, and some further explanation about why the phrase you suggest is the best one to fit the user's question.